# Using functions that take an interface without creating a class the implements said interface

Tags: kotlin, interface, kotlin-js

building alot of binding libraries for a kotlin js project.

i have a ton of interfaces that look like this:

```
external interface FullscreenControlProps {
    var containerId: String?
    var position: String? 
    var style: Any?
}
```

adn then i will need to call a function that uses the above interface as a param

```
fun doSomethingCool(controls:FullscreenControlProps)
```

Can i use that function without creating a seperate class to implement the interface?

Answer (score 2):

No, an instance of an interface cannot exist without a class to implement it.

But you can create what's called an anonymous class using the `object` syntax. This creates the class as a singleton instance "on the fly" without you having to give it a constructor or having to call a constructor. For example:

```
doSomethingCool(object: FullscreenControlProps {
    override var containerId: String? = "Hello"
    override var position: String? = "World"
    override var style: Any? = "1"
})
```

Comment: i will play with that, thank you!